# How to change Wagtail admin Tag wiget to select?

Tags: python, admin, wagtail

I have tags model:

```
class MediaTag(TagBase):
free_tagging = False
color = models.CharField(
    _("Tag color"),
    max_length=7,
    choices=MEDIA_TAG_COLOR_CHOICES
)
site = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailcore.Site',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)


class MediaTagItem(ItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        MediaTag, related_name="tagged_media", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'MediaPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tagged_items'
    )

class MediaPage(AbstractNewsPage, index.Indexed):
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=MediaTagItem, blank=False)
    ...
```

I need to change MediaPage admin widget for the tags feild to select. And set options for it with tags for the same site as the page.
I can change the widget using the register_form_field_override function, but how do I pass choises there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but only with single word tags:

```
from django import forms
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel
from django.apps import apps

class TagSelectPanel(FieldPanel):

    def get_form_options(self, *args):
        options = super().get_form_options(*args)
        options["widgets"] = {
            self.field_name: forms.widgets.Select(),
        }
        return options

    def get_bound_panel(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        panel = super().get_bound_panel(*args, **kwargs)
        model = apps.get_model('news', 'MediaTag')
        choices_queryset = model.objects.all()
        field = panel.form.fields[self.field_name]
        field.widget.choices = [
            (item.name, item.name) for item in choices_queryset
        ]
        return panel


class MediaPage(AbstractNewsPage, index.Indexed):
    ...
    content_panels = AbstractNewsPage.content_panels + [
        TagSelectPanel('tags'),
        ...
    ]
```